# Find a comparable value inside an array property within an Entity

Tags: java, xodus

How do you find if a property that is an array contains a value, what is available by default to Xodus is `txn.find(entityType, propertyName, comparableValue)` to find a value, however, what is the best way to find if an array property contains a value. Suppose I have this:

```
public class EmbeddedArrayIterable implements Serializable, ByteIterable {
}
```

In which I need to compare if a given value, example "cat", is inside the array. What should be the implementation of `EmbeddedArrayIterable` as such it will be able to return the `Entity` to which this "cat" string is in the array of the entity.

As such we can do:

```
// This property is a `EmbeddedArrayIterable` 
// which is a serialized JSON like `["cat","tiger","lion"]`
String propertyName = "keywords"; 
String comparableValue = "cat";
EntityIterable cats = txn.find(entityType, propertyName, comparableValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define a custom property type, then you cannot find an entity by only a part of its value. In your case, it makes sense to use `ComparableSet` value type provided out-of-the-box. Set the property value as a set of items:

```java
final ComparableSet<String> propValue = new ComparableSet<>();
propValue.addItem("cat");
propValue.addItem("tiger");
propValue.addItem("lion");
entity.setProperty("keywords", propValue);
```

You can then get the value using `Entity#getProperty(..)`, cast to `ComparableSet<String>` and modify the set if necessary. You can also find the entity by only a single item of the set:

```java
EntityIterable cats = txn.find(entityType, "keywords", "cat");
```

Comment: Can you put a Comparable as type property of a `ComparableSet`? Example: `ComparableSet<Comparable>`?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to specify the type parameter? Not sure what may be the reason for that.